# Run Selenium tests withSpring Boot webservice launched externally

Tags: java, web-services, selenium, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web service and a Selenium functional test. It uses Selenium as Maven dependency and runs well. I set this up following some tutorials.

However, I also have to start the web service manually (i.e. by java -jar myService.jar) and run tests again the web service.

How can I run the tests in this scenario?

Comment: Do you have any sort of pipeline set up? e.g. Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, I have Jenkins available. Right now building, unit testing and integration testing are already done in the pipeline. Missing only the test of the final artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bash script can be executed before the tests happen to start the application server:

```
java -jar spring-boot-app.jar &
app_pid=$!

server_address='http://localhost:8080'
try_time=60
try_count=0
 until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail $server_address); do
    try_count=$((try_count+1))
    echo "|${try_count}>"
    sleep 10
    if (( try_count > try_time )); then
        echo "Could not connect to server"
        exit 1
    fi
done
echo "Server available"
```

Now the tests can be executed, either by the Jenkins default task or simply by calling them manually, e.g.

```
mvn -U package failsafe:integration-test
```

In the end, the server has to be shut down again. For example using the process id from above.